# Apache not serving after server restart

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I just restarted my server on digital ocean using reboot, and now apache is not serving any pages.  I can ping the IP from my client.  Everything was working fine before the restart.  Here are some outputs from some of the tests I've done so far:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1005/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1774/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1241/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1774/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1703/memcached  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1005/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2991/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2991/apache2
```

Here is result of netstat.  I'm not sure but does this mean that apache is not listening on IPV4 (TCP)??:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1005/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1774/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1241/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1774/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1703/memcached  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1005/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2991/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2991/apache2    
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*                           1703/memcached
```

The error.log seems OK:

```
[Thu Oct 01 09:09:20.131886 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2991]          AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Oct 01 09:09:20.213216 2015] [:notice] [pid 3176] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 3176)
[Thu Oct 01 09:09:20.221458 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2991] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Thu Oct 01 09:09:21.001486 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2991] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 01 09:09:21.002462 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2991] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Have you tried SSH into your server and check for config syntax error?  Try  # httpd -t
# httpd -S  Sample output should say "Syntax OK"

Answer (score 0):

There are various things you can try to resolve the problem:

You can SSH into your server and check for a config syntax error:

```
#httpd -t
#httpd -S
```

You should see a "Syntax OK" message if the httpd.conf is configured properly.

You could check the Apache Error Log File which will point out the exact problem location:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd-error.log
egrep -i 'warn|error' /var/log/httpd-error.log
```

Another option is to check for other processes that may be using port 80 or 443.  Use the netstat command to list open ports and their owners:

```
 # netstat -tulpn
 # netstat -tulpn | grep
 # netstat -tulpn | grep ':80'
```

If other process using port 80 / 443, you need to stop them or assign another port to Apache.

If none of the above things are helpful, you can check for open file FD limits, Apache/PHP/Python/CGI log file size and DNS configuration.

Hopefully there are some ideas you can try there.

Cheers

Comment: I added some outputs to the post above.  I'm not sure, but maybe Apache is not listening on TCP to port 80 and 443, only listening on TCP6??